# Is it possible for two drupal views to share the same pager limit

Tags: drupal, view

I have two separate views 'now' and 'next', they both collectively must only have three items. Is there a way for them to share the same pager limit for example if the 'now' view has one item the 'next' view can only display two items as the pager limit is three.

Comment: how are you displaying the first record in 'now' view if the fields and sort criteria are same as that of 'next' view

Comment: the sort criteria for the two views are the same (date of event asc)

Comment: the filter criteria is different for two views for the now view it filters for items that start date '= now' and the 'next' view filters for items that start date '> now'

Comment: you can use a default pager (no ajax pager) and then display the two views in one page. Then you can alter the second view and put limit and offset by checking the url and getting the page number of the 'now' view. The next view will display based on your logic after getting the page of 'now' view.

Comment: Hi Viswanath, could you just clarify how to set the limit and offset using the page number of the now field

Comment: Since you have low number of possible items you can i.e. make 3 displays for second view. First displaying 1 item, second 2 and third 3.
Then you can use views_embed_view() or even views_get_view_results() to get first view content, see how many results you got and then decide which display of second view will you use.